# Pass data to getServerSideProps from previous page in NextJS

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am developing an e-commerce like website using NextJS.

I will fetch & display list of products in `/products` page. On clicking any product, I'll navigate to `/details/[productId]`, and I'll fetch those product details as follows.

```
// In /details/[productId].js file

export async function getServerSideProps({params}) {
    const res = await fetch(`https:my-api-url/api/products/${params.productId}`)
    const product = await res.json()
    return {
        props: {
            product
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

Everything looks good till this step. But I thought to reduce number of database read count, hence instead of fetching product detail again in `detail` page, I planned to use the data fetched in the previous page (`/products`) which will have the information about the product. Hence I need a way to pass those product object into next screen `/details/[productId]`'s getServerSideProps (to achieve SSR for SEO purposes).

**Workaround**

One solution I currently have is to `stringify` the product json and pass it via query parameter and get it back in `getServerSideProps({params, query})`. But it just spams my url in the browser which isn't look good at all.

**Expectation**

Is there any other way to pass the data into `getServerSideProps` function so that it will utilize the data to generate the whole page in server itself. Please guide me to overcome this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.. (:

Comment: if you have found the answer for this query,then please post it. Even i'm stuck with this issue.

Comment: @Karthik not yet bro, currently I'm hitting the service twice in each page. give an upvote to the question so that anyone will notice the question.

Comment: but this approach seems flawed cuz when someone gets the link of your /page/[pageId] directly there is going to be no data passed from somewhere but.
NOTE: if I am getting something wrong please let me know cuz I am just starting out with nextjs and I have no knowledge of how it works

Comment: and also I think that you will be overloading the request object with data that could easily be generated on the server. plus sending some sensitive information will be a problem in some cases

Answer (score 1):

You can bring in a custom server as express that provides [`locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) property available through the lifetime of your application or request.

```js
const next = require('next');
const express = require('express');

const app = next({ dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' });
const handle = routes.getRequestHandler(app);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev';


app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();
   
  server.get('/products', async (req, reply) => {
    const products = await //... fetch product with details
    req.app.locals.products =  products;
    return app.render(req, reply, '/path/to/products/page', req.query);
  });
  
  server.get('/details/:productId', async (req, reply) => {
    const {productId} = req.params;
    const {products} = req.app.locals;
    // find product using productId and make available in req.locals
    req.locals.product = // product;
    return app.render(req, reply, '/path/to/product/detail/page', req.query)
  }); 
  
  server.get('*', (req, reply) => {
    return handle(req, reply)
  });

  server.listen(3000);
});
```

> Pay caution to how large your product list grow to avoid running your application out of memory.

You could also return a cookie containing the list of products on the request for products ([See limits for HTTP cookies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-6.1)). Then read that on the product detail page.

Answer (score -1):

> When I enter URL http://localhost:3000/blog/wfe436

```
//getting the meta tags dynamically

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
    // Get external data from the file system, API, DB, etc.
    console.log(params) // here is the data of the url { blogname: 'wfe436' }
    const posts = Data
    // The value of the `props` key will be
    //  passed to the `Home` component
    return {
        props: { posts }
    }
}
```